# appending a string to a ProxyPass or ProxyPassMatch rule with query params

Tags: mod-rewrite, proxy, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy, proxypass

I currently have the following url: `/my-url/?foo=bar`
which then uses the following proxy rule:

```
ProxyPass /my-url/ http://mynewlocation.com/my-url/
ProxyPassReverse /my-url/ http://mynewlocation.com/my-url/
```

so i end up with `http://mynewlocation.com/my-url/?foo=bar`

I want to then add a new string/param to the end of the url i get back, so the original url query params are included, and my new string is added.

As example lets say i wanted
`/my-url/?foo=bar` to become `http://mynewlocation.com/my-url/?foo=bar&test=true`

how would i go about doing that?

i've tried changing it to ProxyPassMatch like so:

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/my-url/(.*) http://mynewlocation.com/my-url/$1&test=true
ProxyPassMatchReverse ^/my-url/(.*) http://mynewlocation.com/my-url/$1&test=true
```

which results in `http://mynewlocation.com/my-url/test=true` so it's just removing the query string, anyone know what i'm doing wrong?

thanks

Comment: did you solve it?